# Dados não foram alterados no banco - laravel 5.7 eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.7

Boa tarde pessoal, estou tentando fazer um update porem os valores inseridos nos campos não salva no banco, segue arquivos para verificarem.

**Index.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<?php
if (session('message')):?>

    <div class="alert alert-success" style=" opacity: 1;">
        {{ session('message') }}
    </div>
 <?php
  else:?>

 <?php
      endif;
       ?> 

  <div class="col-sm-12">

    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">

    </div>
    <div class="card-block">
    <div class="dt-responsive table-responsive">
      <a href="{{route('Aulas.create')}}" class="btn btn-primary ">Cadastrar uma nova aula </a>
  <p> </p>
    <table id="simpletable" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Ritmo</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Dia da Semana</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Horário</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Status</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Alterar</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Excluir</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php
$RowsCount = $Aulas->count();

if($RowsCount >= 0 ):

      foreach($Aulas as $models):
      ?>
      <tr>
        <td style=""><?php echo $models['Ritmo']; ?></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $models['DiaSemana']; ?></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $models['Horario']; ?></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $models['Status']; ?></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
         <a class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-primary btn-icon" href="{{route('Aulas.edit', $models->Id)}}">A</a>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
              <form method="POST" action="{{ route('Aulas.destroy', $models->Id) }}">
                @csrf
                @method('DELETE')
                <button type="submit" name="btn-deletar" class="btn btn-warning btn-outline-warning btn-icon" data-type="success" data-from="top" data-align="right">E</button>
              </form>
      </td>
      </tr>
       <?php
      endforeach;
      else: ?>

      <tr>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>-</td>
      </tr>

       <?php
      endif;
       ?> 
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

@stop
```

**route/web**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

    Route::get('/ListAula', 'CadastrosBasicos\AulasController@Index')->name('aulas'); 

    Route::get('/CadAula', 'CadastrosBasicos\AulasController@create')->name('create');

     Route::get('/edit', 'CadastrosBasicos\AulasController@edit')->name('edit');

    Route::post('/store', 'CadastrosBasicos\AulasController@store')->name('store');

    Route::post('/update', 'CadastrosBasicos\AulasController@update')->name('update'); 

    Route::resource('Aulas','CadastrosBasicos\AulasController');

});
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\CadastrosBasicos;


use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use App\Models\CadastrosBasicos\Aulas;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AulasController extends Controller
{
   public function edit(Request $request, $Id )
    {
         $Aula = Aulas::find($Id);
         return view('CadastrosBasicos.Aulas.Editar', compact('Aula'));
    }



    public function update(Request $request, $Id)
    {
      $AulaDb = Aulas::find($Id);
      $AulaDb->Id = $Id;
      $AulaDb->Ritmo = $request->get('Ritmo');
      $AulaDb->DiaSemana = $request->get('DiaSemana');
      $AulaDb->Horario = $request->get('Horario');
      $AulaDb->Status = $request->get('Status');
      $AulaDb->save();

       return redirect() ->route('aulas')
                       ->with('message', 'Aula Alterada com sucesso!');
    }
}
```

**Moldes**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\CadastrosBasicos;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Aulas extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Aulas';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['Id','Ritmo','Horario','DiaSemana','Status'];

}
```

Comment: Faltou colocar o formulário que está usando para atualizar.

Comment: as suas rotas não tem padrão, e ruim se o projeto for crescendo, os nomes também deveria seguir um nomenclatura, tudo isso é bom para não ter choque de rotas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eai Claudio blz?, seguinte cara, no seu method update, vc informa que está passando um ID, e com esse ID, vc está procurando pela Aula. Mas, na sua rota vc não está passando um ID pra o method, vc deve padronizar a sua rota passando o ID assim:

> Route::post('/update/{aulaId:[0-9]+}', 'CadastrosBasicos\AulasController@update')->name('update');

OBS: Lembre-se de passar o ID no button de update que acessa a rota, como vc não postou o código dela, não sei como está.

E no seu method, vc captura esse ID (Lembrando, vc não precisa inserir o ID novamente um linha que vc está fazendo o update):

> ```
> public function update(Request $request, $aulaId)
> {
>   $data = $request->all();
>   $AulaDb = Aulas::find($aulaId);      
>   $AulaDb->Ritmo = $data->Ritmo;
>   $AulaDb->DiaSemana = $data->DiaSemana;
>   $AulaDb->Horario = $data->Horario;
>   $AulaDb->Status = $data->Status;
>   $AulaDb->save();
>   return redirect() ->route('aulas')
>                    ->with('message', 'Aula Alterada com sucesso!');
> }
> ```

Outra forma que vc pode também fazer é assim, caso, os campos que vc está passando no request sejam iguais aos do banco:

```
public function update(Request $request, $aulaId){
     $aula = Aulas::findOrFail($aulaId);
     $aula = $aula->fill($request->all());
     $aula->save();
}
```